# Equinumerosity of a set and the set Intersection with another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that if $A, B$ two sets, and also:

1. A is Equinumerosity to $A\cap B$
2. $A\cup B\neq B$

then $A$ must be Infinite set.

Comment: *Hint:*  Recall or prove the following statements: $A\cup B \neq B \iff A\setminus B\neq \emptyset$, If $E\subseteq F$ then $|E|\leq |F|$.  Further, $|A|=|A\cap B|+|A\setminus B|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A = A $\cap$ B, then A subset B.
Hence A $\cup$ B = B which contradicts the 2nd premise.

Thus A /= A $\cap$ B.  So A $\cap$ B is a proper subset of A that is equinumerous to A.  Hence A is infinite.